# How do I insert a user-inputted integer into a println statement?

Tags: java

I would like to replace the bit about "The first number is a multiple of the second." with something more like  System.out.print(+int a " is a multiple of" +int b);
Any advice?
The piece of code I'm working with is as follows.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Multiples {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter two integers " );
        int a = scan.nextInt(); // First number input by user
        int b = scan.nextInt(); // Second number input by user

        if ( a % b == 0 )// is a a multiple of b 
            System.out.print("The first number is a multiple of the second.");
        else 
            System.out.print("The first number is not a multiple of the second.");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
System.out.print( a + " is a multiple of " + b); // Or System.out.println()
```

or use [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
System.out.printf("%d is a multiple of %d", a, b);
```

Comment: -1? Feedback is welcome!